# problem connecting to EAP-FAST wireless

Tags: wireless

I have problem connecting to EAP-FAST network on our office wireless. 
Its prompts for the username/password but even after entering it keeps prompting for the same. Below is what i see in logs.

CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=43 -> NAK
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed

Running on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to be a comment but I do not have sufficient privileges to comment on this question.

I have had this issue for a while and have spent quite a bit of time debugging
this problem. Here's my progress so far:

Problem: The wpa_supplicant included with Ubuntu is too old, doesn't support EAP-FAST

Proof: From syslog

`NetworkManager[1252]: <warn> EAP-FAST is not supported by the supplicant`

Solution:

12.10 didn't upgrade the wpa_supplicant version, so I was left to compiling it 
myself.
After a few attempts I could successfully compile the code, downloaded from [this location](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/). I then replaced the default version of wpa_supplicant manually (copied it to **/sbin**, luckily after having backed up the existing executable)

Complications:

- Turns out, the new wpa_supplicant doesn't play well with the older parameters.
  During startup, the wpa_supplicant is called as a dbus service. The exact call is
  stored at /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service. This call fails as the older parameters passed to the wpa_supplicant no longer work. This, in turn, leaves the network manager completely unusable.
- You can manually call the new wpa_supplicant with your own configuration and it does work properly, but network manager integration is missing in this scenario.
- I would greatly appreciate further suggestions.